# Another proof for $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}n^{\frac{1}{n}}=1(n=1,2,\cdots)$.

Tags: proof-verification, alternative-proof

#### Problem

Prove$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}n^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$$where $n=1,2,\cdots$

#### Proof

Notice that $$1=1^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq n^{\frac{1}{n}}=\sqrt[n]{1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdots\sqrt{n}\cdot \sqrt{n}}\leq \frac{n-2+2\sqrt{n}}{n}<\frac{n+2\sqrt{n}}{n}=1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}.$$
Thus, $$1 \leq n^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq 1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\to 1(n \to \infty).$$
By the squeeze theorem, we may obtain $$\lim_{n \to \infty}n^{\frac{1}{n}}=1.$$

Comment: What specifically is your question? Do you want feedback on your proof as suggested by the initial tag, or alternative proofs as maybe suggested by the title and the new tag. // Presumably that's also a duplicate but this is orthogonal.

Comment: It seems correct to me!

Comment: What is the other (or others) proof you are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the limit is $L = 1$, let us prove this using the definition of a limit:
$$\forall \epsilon > 0,  \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } \vert  n^\frac{1}{n} - 1 \vert < \epsilon, \quad \forall n > n_0$$

Notice that the following are equivalent

1. $\mid n^\frac{1}{n} - 1 \mid < \epsilon $
2. $(1- \epsilon)^n < n < (1+\epsilon)^n$

Note that $(1- \epsilon)^n < 1 \le n$.
As for $(1 + \epsilon)^n$, use Binomial theorem as follows
$$
(1+\epsilon)^n = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}\epsilon^i > \binom{n}{2}\epsilon^{2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \epsilon^2
$$
Choose $n_0 = \lceil 1 + \frac{2}{\epsilon^2}  \rceil$,
we have 
$$
n < \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \epsilon^2 <(1+\epsilon)^n 
$$